# MS ACCESS count/sum number of rows, with no duplicates

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, distinct

I have the following table which I need to count the total number of rows without including any duplicate records.

```
CustomerID
test1
test1
test2
test3
test4
test4
```

As you can see, the total number of rows is 6 but there are two test1 and two test4, and I wish the query to return 4.  IOW, I want to count unique values in `CustomerID`.

I've tried sub query but didn't get it to work for me.

**-- Update 27/06/2012 --**

Thanks, both worked for me:

> 1. SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( SELECT CustomerID FROM TheTable GROUP BY CustomerID ) as
> 2. SELECT COUNT(*)
>      FROM
>      (
>          SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID FROM TheTable
>      ) AS sub;

I now need a query to keep only those CustomerID which were added today, then count them.

For example,

```
CustomerID DateAdded
test1 25/06/2012
test1 25/06/2012
test2 26/06/2012
test3 27/06/2012 - Today
test4 27/06/2012 - Today
test4 27/06/2012 - Today
```

then it needs to return 3.

I've tried adding in the following query into the two solutions provided, but couldn't get either of them to work/return the value I want.

> HAVING (([TheTable].DateAdded)=Date());

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second suggestion in dbaseman's answer looks correct to me.  This alternative should also work.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID FROM TheTable
    ) AS sub;
```

I don't know whether it offers any advantage over dbaseman's `GROUP BY`.  If you decide to test both approaches, please add a comment to tell us what you find.

Based on your comment, you want to evaluate "*only those records that were added today*".  Since you didn't give us enough information about your table, I will pretend it includes a Date/Time field named `date_added`.  And each time you add a record you store the current date, with the time component as midnight, in that field.  In that case you can add a `WHERE` clause to the subquery to ask the db engine to consider only those rows where `date_added` is equal to today's date.  The `Date()` function will give you today's date, with midnight as the time component.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID FROM TheTable
        WHERE date_added = Date()
    ) AS sub;
```

Once you replace `date_added` with your field name, that should work provided my assumptions were correct.  However if your `date_added` values include any time component other than midnite, you will have to revise the `WHERE` clause to capture *all* Date/Time values from today.

```
WHERE date_added >= Date() AND date_added < (Date() + 1)
```

Comment: Hi, this also worked for me, but I've got one other problem that I couldn't solve, could you please see my first post on the top? Thank you.

Comment: I've tried, you were correct about the data_added (no time component), however, when i tried

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID FROM TheTable WHERE date_added = Date()) AS sub; it didn't work, either syntax or bracketing error. It's weird though, as the query you and @dbaseman provided for my first question worked fine initially, but after I modified anything, even adding in only a space character, they became borken..

Comment: If you're using Access 2003, switch back to SQL View after Access complains, and check whether it has altered the backeting around the subquery.

Comment: Hey @HansUp, I replaced open brackets with square brackets outside the sub query and everything works fine now. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 4):

<s>This would work in SQL, I think it should also in Access:</s>

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerID) FROM TheTable
```

*Edit: Per Jeff in comments, Access doesn't support the above syntax.*

This should work for sure though:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( SELECT CustomerID FROM TheTable GROUP BY CustomerID ) a
```

To restrict by date

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( 
    SELECT TheTable.CustomerID FROM TheTable GROUP BY CustomerID 
    WHERE TheTable.DateAdded >= Date()
) a
```

Comment: The second answer is correct. Access doesn't have COUNT(DISTINCT). You need to create a subquery which groups by the field you want to be distinct and count off of that.

Comment: @dbaseman Hi, this worked for me. I then tried to write another line of conditional query which will keep only those records that were added today and count them, could you please refer to my first post and see what I have done wrong in my codes? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user1481722 you might want to consider opening another question in that case.  But please see my updated answer, hopefully that helps. (I'm assuming your table has a column named *DateAdded* or similar, to track the timestamp.)