# MS Access: divide result set into multiple pieces by text value or number of rows

Tags: sql, comparison, ms-access-2007

I have a query against an Item table. This is all the items our library has, e.g., books, DVDs,CDs, etc.

I have to send a tab-delimited file that contains data on all these items.

There are over 100,000 items.

I'm stuck using MS Access.

Access can pull all the data, but it cannot send the result set via email because it is too big (over 65,535 rows; I am aware that later versions of Excel past 2007 can hold more rows but that does not help me).
All the columns are text data. So normal relational operators won't work (I tried).

I need to split the result set into two or three result sets in order to get it from Access to Excel. The need for Excel is that this is how the vendor expects it, and it needs to be tweaked some before shipping.

How can I divide it?

I have thought of at least two ways

1. If I can count rows, I can tell Access to use the first 60,0000  rows it gets. How do I tell it do that and then fetch only the second set of all the rows past 60,000. I  have not figured out how to do this.
2. Divide based upon a field. The only field that is unique is the barcode, e.g., "30001001672906" Usually, the barcode is 14 numbers in length. I have experimented with using StrComp in a where clause, but I have a problem:

The barcodes are not in sorted order before they are fetched.  "Order by" works on the result set, not how the data is processed before it is selected.

I am at a loss as to how to accomplish my big goal. That's the one that matters, not the particular way to fix my SQL to get it.  I've looked at some pages, such as those below but not found a solution.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Table-of-operators-e1bc04d5-8b76-429f-a252-e9223117d6bd#__toc272228349
[MS ACCESS count/sum number of rows, with no duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201351/ms-access-count-sum-number-of-rows-with-no-duplicates)
http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/strcomp.php

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the problem with 2.

```
SELECT barcode FROM items ORDER BY barcode
```

Open a Recordset on that, move to record 60000, get the barcode

```
rst.Move 60000
strBarcode = rst!barcode
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243789%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Then build your queries dynamically.

```
myQuerydef.SQL = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE barcode <= '" & strBarcode & "'"
```

Export the query e.g. with `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`

```
myQuerydef.SQL = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE barcode > '" & strBarcode & "'"
```

Export to second file.

If you need more than two files, use an array instead of strBarcode and do

```
myQuerydef.SQL = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE barcode > '" & Barcode(i) & _
                 "' AND barcode <= '" & Barcode(i+1) & "'"
```